# Removing last character in a string if it meets a condition

Tags: python

I have a `.txt` file that includes multiple ids. I want to remove the last character of the ids, if  the 5th and 6th character in each id is equal to '12'. I have tried to run this Python code, but it returns unchanged ids. What could be the problem? Below I am providing the code that I am using to run this.

```py
def process_image_ids(multiple_ids):
    processed_ids = []
    for multiple_id in multiple_ids:
        if multiple_id[4:6] == "12":
            processed_id = multiple_id[:-1]  
        else:
            processed_id = multiple_id 
        processed_ids.append(processed_id)
    return processed_ids

with open ('x\y\list_multiple_ids.txt', 'r') as f:
    multiple_ids = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]

processed_ids = process_image_ids(multiple_ids)
```

Example of my the .txt file lines:

```
01MA12023654894C
02MAYBAM369589000
```

Comment: Perhaps its because you never call your function `process_image_ids()`?

Comment: Change the line `multiple_id = multiple_id[:-1]` to `processed_id = multiple_id[:-1]` and add an `if` to the start of the line above

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the last piece of code, where I call the function. Updating it :)

Comment: Also fix the `if` in the function. If your real code runs ok, what you posted is different.

Comment: 1. Get a good IDE. In my IDE: missing if is immediately highlighted. When if is added, dead store to multiple_id is highlighted. 2. Learn how to use a debugger. See [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: Please post your real code. What you have posted would produce syntax errors. Plus, you still never call your function.

Comment: The `processed_ids = process_image_ids(multiple_ids)` you added should be the last line!

Comment: @JustinaVitkutė, your solution can be greatly optimized

Comment: Have adjusted the code. Still the same result- not doing what it should. Have I overseen something?

Comment: So you also need to post a small sample of lines from your file. At least one line needs to be one that will be modified.

Comment: Ok, I've tried your code with a file of the two sample lines and it works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides of solutions suggested the whole processing can be considerably enhanced:

- instead of reading all lines with `f.readlines()` iterate over the file iterator `f` directly
- omit redundant `for` loop (through the external function) and check the needed conditions explicitly on the fly

---

```
with open ('x\y\list_multiple_ids.txt', 'r') as f:
    processed_ids = [id_[:-1] if (id_ := line.strip())[4:6] == '12' else id_
                     for line in f]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Always a good idea to enhance the process. I have also tried this approach, but the code still does not remove the last character of my ids.

Comment: @JustinaVitkutė, can you share a link with a sample of your file?

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the code with example of ids. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: @JustinaVitkutė, that won't help. Try to add `newline=''` param to your `open()` call

Answer (score 1):

The issue in your code is that you are using the equality operator (==) in the line `multiple_id[4:6] == "12"`. Instead, you should use the equality operator to check if the 5th and 6th characters are equal to `"12"` and then modify the multiple_id accordingly. Here's the corrected code:

```py
def process_image_ids(multiple_ids):
    processed_ids = []
    for multiple_id in multiple_ids:
        if multiple_id[4:6] == "12":  # Use '==' for comparison, not assignment.
            multiple_id = multiple_id[:-1]
        processed_ids.append(multiple_id)
    return processed_ids

with open('x\y\list_multiple_ids.txt', 'r') as f:
    multiple_ids = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]

processed_ids = process_image_ids(multiple_ids)
```

You can also verify it by:

```py
for id in processed_ids:
    print(id)
```

Comment: I have adjusted the code in regards to your comments. Still not doing what it should. Did I oversee something? :)

Answer (score 1):

1. `process_image_ids` is not used anywhere in this code snippet
2. `multiple_id[4:6] == "12":` this one should start with `if`
3. `multiple_id = multiple_id[:-1]` here you are redefining `multiple_id`, but I think was is meant is to define `processed_id`

```
def process_image_ids(multiple_ids):
    processed_ids = []
    for multiple_id in multiple_ids:
        if multiple_id[4:6] == "12":
            processed_id = multiple_id[:-1]  
        else:
            processed_id = multiple_id 
        processed_ids.append(processed_id)
    return processed_ids

with open ('x\y\list_multiple_ids.txt', 'r') as f:
    multiple_ids = process_image_ids([line.strip() for line in f.readlines()])
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have adjusted the code, but it still returns the unchanged ids :(

Answer (score 0):

From the description of your use case, it looks like you have an ID on each line of the txt file. If so, I think that the problem might lie in the fact that your

```
process_id = multiple_id[:-1]
```

is removing the trailing newline character `\n` instead of the "last" character of the ID that you want to remove.
You could test it using `line.strip('\n')`. If you still want to remove also possible whitespaces, use `line.strip(' \n')` (note the extra space).